# Use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController's displayedProperties with ARC

Tags: objective-c

I'm using this code snipped in an ARC-enabled iOS 5+ project:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonAddressProperty]];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as it results in a compiling error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_kABPersonAddressProperty", referenced from: …

kABPersonAddressProperty returns an `ABPropertyID` which is basically an `int` so I thought ARC shouldn't care about it.

Why doesn't this work and how can I fix that?

Comment: I just copied and build your code without any errors in a test project (iOS5 + ARC) -> Are you sure you have added al the right frameworks to your project? (Which ones do you have linked?)

Comment: Whoops … I only did an `#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>` but missed to `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`. Now it's working. Thanks for pushing me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have added the appropriate frameworks via the "Build Phases" tab under project settings. Scroll down to the "Link Binary with Libraries," and click the + icon.

Also make sure that you have also `#imported` the appropriate .h files in the respective class.